# Spam without links?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, spam, ethics

So I just visited the front page of SO and noticed [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65313/shachris23) had bumped like 5 questions that were all very similar and all about Algorithms. I suspected spam, so I looked on all of them. He posted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256721/good-book-for-thinking-in-terms-of-algorithms/2614654#2614654) to all 5 questions. I flagged all of them. But now looking back, could I have been wrong?

The answer he gave was informative(from what I skimmed over), and had no links in it. So is it still spam? Does duplication count as spam?

edit: [actually there was more than just 5 duplicates.](https://stackoverflow.com/api/useranswers.html?userid=65313&page=1&pagesize=30&sort=recent)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's spam.

Absolutely no reason to carbon copy a generic answer shilling a book on that many questions. Heck I ran out of flags flagging them all.

Answer (score 1):

He acts like a spammer, he looks like a spammer, he smells like a spammer.

Ok, maybe I'm exaggerating a bit. Even if he is really an enthusiastic fan and did not want to spam (what I doubt), he still did it. Flag and go on.

Comment: it just seemed non-spammy to me because it didn't have a single link.

Comment: External links might have tripped some of the capachas, who knows?

Comment: @ear: most SO users are not too stupid to search for a book title. You don't need a link to spam.

Answer (score 1):

Well. It ***could*** just be a really enthusiastic reader of the book...

But that is not how it feels to me because

1. The particular instance you linked looks to be off-topic
2. When I check the [activity page for the user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65313?tab=activity#tab-top) I see 6 posts in 3 minutes

**Side note:** This user's <s>has taken a *big* rep hit previously. Looking into what might have caused it.</s> previous activity is pretty normal and includes offering two substantial bounties. Perhaps the team would like to check with the user to see if anything untoward has happened lately.